# How to Get in to loop if system command is succesful in perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I am running a perl script, am running a system command like below

{{{{ I want to If _ else code to execute only when there is successful output from the system command

```
$data='df -h | grep /dev/shm'

system($data); 

if($data!=0)(Go inside if system command is success) 
{ 

    print "some value"

    if(

    {
        print "A";


    }

    else

    {
        print "B";
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance i am newbie in perl

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "If _ else" code to execute only when there is successful output from the system command then:

```
$data=`df -h | grep /dev/shm`;

if($data =~ m/\/dev\/shm/) {
# yes output found , do something
} else {
# no output, do some other thing
}
```

Update: use back tick instead of system function.

Comment: The return value of `system()` is not the STDOUT of the command but its exit code.

Comment: oh god, i'm sorry , confused between PHP and Perl

Comment: Personally i would prefer `qx"df -h | grep /dev/shm"` which does the same thing, but that is just because i tend to confuse backticks with ' when reading my own code. ^^